# Return many inner tags

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to return many inner XML tags `payment_response` in response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment_responses page="1" per_page="100" total_count="23" pages_count="1">
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>authorize3d</transaction_type>
        <status>pending_async</status>
    </payment_response>
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>authorize3d</transaction_type>
        <status>pending_async</status>
    </payment_response>
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>authorize3d</transaction_type>
        <status>pending_async</status>
    </payment_response>
</payment_responses>
```

I tried this:

**XML Tag: PaymentResponses**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_responses")
public class PaymentResponses {

    @XmlElement(name = "payment_response")
    public PaymentResponse paymentResponse;

    @XmlElement(name = "technical_message")
    public String technical_message;

    public PaymentResponses() {
    }

    public PaymentResponses(PaymentResponse paymentResponse) {
        this.paymentResponse = paymentResponse;
    }

    public PaymentResponses(String technical_message) {
        this.technical_message = technical_message;
    }
}
```

**XML Tag PaymentResponse:**

```
public class PaymentResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transaction_type;
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    public String status;

    public PaymentResponse() {
    }   

    public PaymentResponse(String unique_id) {
        this.unique_id = unique_id;
    }
```

**Generate response:**

```
    List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = ........;

    PaymentResponse dd = null;

    for (int e = 0; e < paymentTransactions.size(); e++) {
        PaymentTransactions res = paymentTransactions.get(e);

        dd = new PaymentResponse(res.getUnique_id());

    }

    PaymentResponses pt = new PaymentResponses(dd);

    return pt;
```

But I always get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<payment_responses>
    <payment_response>
        <unique_id>01h90ogbevoh5jdwi5ropbw96g02kkxd</unique_id>
    </payment_response>
</payment_responses>
```

How I can get many inner  tags?

Comment: There is no collection (like a `List<>`, etc.) in one of your classes.

Comment: Can you paste a working example, please?